# Nodejs closures and res object in a callback function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, closures

I want to import some data from a json file (which contains a json array of objects) into mongodb using mongoose. When the route **'/import'** is called I load the file via "require" and start iterating.

```
router.get('/import', function (req, res) {
  var data = require('../import/1.json');
  nTotal = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < nAppCount; i++) {
    var obj = new MyObject(data[i]);
    obj.save(check);
  }
});
```

Since JSHint warns me not to **"make functions inside a loop"**, I created my function called **check** as follows:

```
function check (err,doc){
  nProcessed++;
  if (err) {
    logger.log('error', err.message, err.errors);
  } else {
    logger.log('debug', "%d of %d processed",nProcessed, nTotal);
    if (nProcessed===nTotal) {
      res.render('index');
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected until the end but when all objects are processed I get:

> ReferenceError: res is not defined

Isn't "check" supposed to "know" **res** variable being a closure function? How am I going to access "res"?

Note: I can make it work if I ignore jsHint warning.

Comment: Put the declaration of `check()` at the top of that callback function you're passing to `router.get()`.

Comment: Indeed, you have to be in the same (functional) scope in order to be able to capture the closure. See [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: is `nAppCount` supposed to be `nTotal`? if so, the right way to do this would be with a forEach loop if `data` is an array, thus avoiding this problem entirely. I tend to avoid using for loops all together in favor of functional methods that create their own scope to avoid any var leakage.

Comment: Where is the function `check` actually defined?

Comment: Yes "check" was defined outside! That was the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing to understand here is, the variables are enclosed during the creation of the function not during the invocation of the function.

In your case, when the function `check` is created, it doesn't enclose `res` or `req`. So, even when you invoke it from other functions, it will not be aware of them.

To fix this, you can simply define the `check` function within the `router.get` and before the `for` loop. For example,

```
router.get('/import', function (req, res) {
  ...

  function check(err, doc) {
    ...
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nAppCount; i++) {
    (new MyObject(data[i])).save(check);
  }

});
```